# withNavigationFocus React-Navigation alternative for class component after upgrade from 3.x to 6.x

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am currently updating the version of my application, and I have a function that is used that no longer exists, I tried several things according to the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen)
but I get either an "Invalid Hook Call" error or something else...

The problem without the withNavigationFocus function is that when the screen is rendered, the data is not displayed. I have to press Cmd+S to refresh and have the data on the screen. Knowing that the props are linked to Redux.

This is the line that causes the problem:

`export default withNavigationFocus(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home));`

I can't find an alternative so far, does anyone have an idea?

[Upgrade doc link here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/upgrading-from-4.x/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install a backward compatibility package and you can continue to use HOCs  `withNavigation` and  `withNavigationFocus`.

I`npm install @react-navigation/native@^5.x @react-navigation/compat@^5.x @react-navigation/stack@^5.x`

It was designed with React Navigation 5. I didn't test with version 6

Comment: `@react-navigation/compat` is not compatible with `@react-navigation/native@6.x`

Answer (score 0):

For 6.x use `useIsFocused` hook instead, [You can wrap your class component in a function component to use the hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/#using-with-class-component):

```js
class Profile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Get it from props
    const { isFocused } = this.props;
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return <Profile {...props} isFocused={isFocused} />;
}
```

Comment: How would you wrap and export what the OP needs? `export default withNavigationFocus(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home))`